# Subnetting/Network splitting

Tags: networking, ip

I have general Networking and Subnetting Knowledge, but I am unsure on how to go abouteven beginning to answer these question [spleitting the network then answering the questions below]. If anyone can help/show me how its done via step by step approach, that would be awesome.

Given the **IP Address:** `198.14.45.128/26`

Split it up into 3 subnets containing

- Application Development (AD): 24 usable IP addresses
- Application Testing (AT): 10 usable IP addresses
- Administration and Accounting(AA): 3 usable IP addresses

What is the broadcast address for this department’s subnet?

What is the mask value for this department’s subnet?

What are the first and the last usable IP addresses in this department’s subnet?

Please use Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) notation.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

There are excellent guides on the internet on how to subnet networks. A quick Google for 'subnetting for beginners' should yield more than enough results ([good Cisco guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html)).

You could subnet it like this:

```
198.14.45.128/27 (30 hosts, broadcast: 198.14.45.159, first/last: 129, 158)
198.14.45.160/28 (14 hosts, broadcast: 198.14.45.175, first/last: 161, 174)
198.14.45.176/29 (6  hosts, broadcast: 198.14.45.183, first/last: 177, 182)
```